# Group Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $$H=
  \left\{\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & b \\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)\Bigg\vert b\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
be a group under multiplication.
How do I show that $H\cong \mathbb{R}$? Do I show a bijective, homomorphism between $H$ and $\mathbb{R}$, or should I use the Isomorphism Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $f:H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(1,b,0,1)=b$. Now, you have to show that this map is a homomorphism, i.e. $f(M_1*M_2)=f(M_1)*f(M_2)$ and that this map is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

Maryam's answer is exactly correct, but I feel I should make a couple quick remarks about terminology. You used the phrase "Do I show that $H$ is bijective and homorphic?", which doesn't really make sense. $H$ is a set (in fact, a group), which doesn't make sense to be called "bijective". A bijection is a *function* from one set to another, and so it only makes sense to describe a function as bijective, not a set.

Same with the word *homomorphic*. A function can be a homomorphism, but a set is not.

The point then is that if you want to show that two groups are isomorphic---which means that there exists an isomorphism between the two groups---in this case, $H$ and $\mathbb{R}$, you need to describe a function between the two groups.

The function that Maryam describes is one such choice. And then, as she says, you need to prove that the *function* has the properties of being a bijection and being a homomorphism.